# Transition width when element changes width CSS

Tags: css

Today I spent whole day figuring out how to achieve this, but didn't manage to do it.

I wanted to animate flex-shrink on search area, when select is clicked it changes width. I want that transition to be smooth.

I have tried setting min-width on select and than transitioning it.
Also I was searching if it's possible to animate flex shrink but couldn't managed to make it work.
I tried putting transition for width on all elements.

Can somebody help me with this?
[image]

```js
let select = document.getElementById("select");
select.addEventListener("click", function() {
    select.style.width = '200px';
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.logo,
.search,
.im-expanding {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.logo {
  width: 125px;
}

.search {
  margin: 0 64px;
  width: 100%;
}

.im-expanding {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width:auto;
  transition: width 2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="search">
    <div class="search-box">
      <p>Search ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="im-expanding">
    <select id="select" name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      more stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a width (or min-width) for your select and add a transition on it.

Then, you've just to increase the width when the select is on focus.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.logo,
.search,
.im-expanding {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.logo {
  width: 125px;
}

.search {
  margin: 0 64px;
  width: 100%;
}

.im-expanding {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  white-space: nowrap; /* If you want to have your select label inline */
}

#select {
  width: 100px; /* OR min-width */
  transition: all 2s ease-in;
}

#select:focus {
  width: 200px; /* OR min-width */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="logo">logo</div>
  <div class="search">
    <div class="search-box">
      <p>Search ...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="im-expanding">
    <select id="select" name="cars">
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div>
      more stuff here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is what you want but you can try to use that :

```
.search:hover {
     // You put your modification here
}
```

when you click on it that would be change like you want.

Comment: or :active for as it is being clicked